# ¿Como hacer una petición http.put correctamente con ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, http, ionic2

Estoy haciendo una peticion put pero me devuelve un error, no se que estoy haciendo mal

```
this.http.put( url,body).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log('se completo la consulta creo que con exito', [data, this.modificiaciones]);
     },
    err => {
        console.log("error de la consulta: ", err);
    }
)
```

El error es el siguiente `OPTIONS  net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`
y el `console.log` dice que el error es: `Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}`
Si elimino el método `.subscribe()` no sale ningún error, pero reviso si el registro de mi tabla en la base de datos fue modificado y no es modificado.

Las peticiones `post` funcionan perfectamente, es con el `put` es que tengo problemas

Answer (score 1):

Debes añadirle las cabeceras

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Y en la petición

```
this.http.put( url,body, {headers: headers})
```